# Jekyll code highlighting with markdown

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I want to highlight some code in Jeckyll. With liquid tags it works and with kramdown it doesn't:

````
# This is highlighted
{% highlight C %}
void foo(){
}
{% endhighlight %}

# These aren't
~~~ C
void foo(){
}
~~~

``` C
void foo(){
}
```
````

The relevant parts of my `_config.yml`:

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

Does Jekyll not support markdown code blocks? If I stick this in github pages, will it work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GitHub Pages uses Pygments](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#defaults) as the default syntax highlighter and the Liquid tag that wraps your code generates a lot of additional markup in the resulting HTML to make the code look pretty.

The back-tick and tilde Markdown notation simply wrap your code in `<pre><code class="language-c">` tags. If you want to use Markdown and have the resulting HTML be syntax highlighted you can add a client-side solution to your HTML templates, such as [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/).